# ASP.NET: How to get the virtual path of a file from a generic handler?

Tags: asp.net, resolveurl, resolveclienturl

How can i resolve a virtual path to a file into a path, suitable for the browser, from within a generic .ashx handler?

e.g. i want to convert:

```
~/asp/ClockState.aspx
```

into

```
/NextAllowed/asp/ClockState.aspx
```

---

If i were a WebForm `Page`, i could call `ResolveUrl`:

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~/asp/ClockState.aspx")
```

which resolves to:

```
/NextAllowed/asp/ClockState.aspx
```

---

But i'm not a WebForm Page, i'm a generic handler. You know, that `IHttpHandler` object with all kinds of things injected:

```
public class ResetClock : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {
        //[process stuff]

        //Redirect client
        context.Response.Redirect("~/asp/ClockState.aspx", true);
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the VirtualPathUtility class to do this.  This contains various methods for working with paths.  The one you need is ToAbsolute(), which will convert a relative path to an absolute one.

```
var path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/asp/ClockState.aspx");
```

However, you can use the tilde in Response.Redirect calls anyway, so the following would still work:

```
Response.Redirect("~/asp/ClockState.aspx");
```

You do not need to convert the URL to an absolute path before using Response.Redirect.

Comment: i thought i had tried simply `Response.Redirect(...)` and it didnt' take into account the virtual folder. But both `VirtualPathUtility` and just `Redirect` work. +1 accepted.